# Speeding up postgres query

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have table 'auctions' with 60k records.
It has a vector column that contains tsearch vectors like below

```
auctions.tsvector_content_tsearch
107658 | '-75':75 '-83':81 '0.265':49 '0.50':140 '1':62 '1000':61 '1080':38 '16':39 '160':91 '170':86 '1920':36 '1920x1080':65,69 '2':154 '219':129 '23':3,20 '23.0':31 '236v3lsb':6,23 '24':164 '24.75':134 '250':58 '3.190':117 '30':80 '426':127 '5':54 '5.0':99 '56':74 '566':125 '9':40 'black':45 'cal':32 'cd/m2':59 'compatible':158 'czarny':46 'czas':51 'czuwać':139 'częstotliwość':71,77 'd':110,114 'd-sub':109 'dodatkowy':146,152 'dvi':7,24,113 'dvi-d':112 'ekran':30 'energia':131,137 'energy':97 'epeat':100 'ergonomics':104 'full':41 'g':120 'gs':106 'gwarancja':153,161 'hd':42 'hz':76 'informacja':151 'jasność':56 'kabel':147,149 'kensington':156 'kg':116,118 'khz':82 'kolor':43 'kontrast':60 'kąt':83,88 'lcd':2,15,19 'led':4,21 'lina':28 'lock':157 'maksymalny':64 'matryca':34,53,57 'miejsce':165 'miesiąc':163 'mm':50 'monitor':1,14,18,96 'mś':55 'nazwać':12 'norma':93 'obudowa':44 'odchylać':72,78 'ogólny':17 'okres':159 'opis':16 'optymalny':68 'philips':5,11,22 'piksel':66,70 'pionowy':73,85 'plamka':48 'pobór':130,136 'poziom':90 'poziomy':79,90 'producent':10 'przekątna':29 'przeć':133 'reakcja':52 'rodzina':25 'rohs':102 'rozdzielczość':63,67 'rękojmia':160 'serwis':167 'serwisować':166 'silver':101 'specyfikacja':8 'spełniać':94 'star':98 'stopień':87,92 'sub':111 'techniczny':9 'tryb':138 'tryba':138 'tuv':103,105 'typ':13,33 'v':27 'v-line':26 'vga':150 'waga':115 'wbudować':142 'widzenia':84,89 'widzenie':84,89 'widzieć':84,89 'wielkość':47 'wuxga':35 'wymiar':119 'wyposażenie':145 'wyposażyć':145 'x':37,121,123,126,128 'zasilacz':143 'zasilać':148 'zewn':108 'zewnętrzny':168 'złączać':107 'złącze':107 'łat':155 'ś':122
```

Table auction has an index on that column:

```
    "auctions_tsvector_content_tsearch_idx" gin (tsvector_content_tsearch)
```

When I search for some matching vectors query takes about 4000-5000ms; that is too long.
Is there any way to speed things up here?

```
EXPLAIN SELECT auctions.id FROM auctions WHERE (auctions.tsvector_content_tsearch @@ to_tsquery('polish', 'lcd'));


           QUERY PLAN                          
--------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on auctions  (cost=0.00..6598.02 rows=7762 width=4)
   Filter: (tsvector_content_tsearch @@ '''lcd'''::tsquery)
(2 rows)
```

_ EDIT __

Ok I think I found a problem: polish dictionary. 
Using standard postgres dictionary fix long time problem. 
Thanks for tips

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the planner estimated that sequential scan is going to be faster than using the index. Try the following:

- `SET enable_seqscan=off` (useful for test, however - do not use it in production)
- raising the stats target

That behaviour sometimes occurs with GIN indices. Check [this thread](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2011-11/msg01754.php) on PostgreSQL mailing list. You can also consult the official [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-indexes.html) about this issue.

Comment: Turning enable_seqscan off is a workaround and useful during testing, but not for production. Fix the real problem, like better stats.

Comment: Completely agree. Purpose of turning enable_seqscan off was to see execution plan and query speed improvement with indices, in production environment that is not an option.